# Is it possible to repeat or redistribute a Bluetooth signal?

Tags: networking, bluetooth, hardware

Let's say hypothetically that I have 3 devices that are all compatible and Bluetooth enabled.

- Device #1 - A fitness watch of some kind that you wear on your wrist.
- Device #2 - Arbitrary state device with master/slave BT chip(s)
- Device #3 - Bluetooth enabled lights / decorations

Pairings:

- Device #1 <-> Device #2
- Device #2 <-> Device #3 (multiple of them throughout a room, maybe 5 or 6 Device3's)

Is there a way/easy way/accepted way to repeat the signal from #1 to all the #3s? I was hoping #2 could act as a hub maintaining state, but let the Bluetooth signal pass straight through to all the #3s (without #1 needing to directly connect to all the #3s individually).

What would be the best way to approach this kind of situation?

I think what I'm basically describing is like an Ethernet switch but for Bluetooth.

Comment: Do you have the possibility to program the Bluetooth-Chip on Device #2?

Comment: Can you give a little more context about your application? Is Device #1 a master, and #3s are slaves? If Device #1 is within range of the #3 Devices, can it normally pair with and control them in some way?

Comment: @Fuzzyma At this point, it's pretty open in order to make it work. Device #2 hasn't been built yet, and that's what I want to buy parts/program in order to make this system work.

Comment: @bsa Ordinarily, Device #1 can pair and control Device #3s. I need it to go through a hub, #2, so I can redistribute its command to many, or to specific, Device #3s without individual connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "no", there is not an easy or standard way to do this. What you are looking for would be a Bluetooth repeater. Bluetooth repeater devices do exist, but are proprietary, not standardized. For example, [this one](http://www.stromgraf.com/sma-bluetooth-repeater) from a German solar power manufacture, specific to their devices.

Usually, Bluetooth networks are a simple star topology with a single master and one or more slaves  - a [piconet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piconet). However, it is possible to join multiple piconets into a larger [scatternet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scatternet).

The longer answer is that it is possible, but will require software support from Device #2. That may involve custom software or firmware development. Depending on your application, it may be simpler to consider adding another form of wireless connectivity into the system, such as [wireless Ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11).

Comment: It's a shame that Bluetooth switch-type device doesn't exist. Creating custom software/firmware is acceptable since Device #2 will be custom built.

Comment: Not really the answer I was looking for, but I guess it'll have to suffice as no one else is capable of answering.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be quite what you're looking for, but Aircable claims to have a [device](http://www.aircable.net/products/host-xr3.php) that will extend your Bluetooth range. I haven't tried it, but there's a [review](http://the-gadgeteer.com/2007/09/03/aircable_host_xr_long_range_bluetooth_dongle/) of an older version that indicates that it does work, though perhaps not as well as it claims. There's a (newer?) version available on [Amazon](http://amzn.to/2bTsExb).

Comment: It's not really a range problem. It's more like an ethernet switch or a USB hub where there's 1 input and 10+ outputs. 

I want to duplicate a singular signal and then programmatically duplicate the signal to other devices.